# Copy data from one server to another server

Tags: sql-server

I have source server as ABC and target server as XYZ

I need to copy some of the tables from ABC to XYZ but I don't need all the records, I just need one days worth of data and I need to refresh every day?

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two databases are `on same server` you can follow these steps:

1. Create copy table in ABC database.
2. Use SQL Server agent to create a SQL Server schedule job every day to run below script:

```sql
truncate XXXTable; --clear XXXTable
insert into XXXTable select * from XYZ..XXXTable; --copy
```

If your two database are `not on same server` you can follow these steps:

1. Create a XYZ `dblink` in ABC database.

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver  @server = N'Server ',   @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'dblinkName',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'sa',@rmtpassword='########';
GO
```

2. Create copy table in ABC database.
3. Use SQL Server agent to create a SQL Server schedule job every day to run below script:

```sql
truncate XXXTable; --clear XXXTable
insert into XXXTable select * from [dblinkname].XYZ..XXXTable; --copy
```

---

#### Edit

> How to copy just one day worth of data

You have to add a createtime column and using `sysdate -1 day` to filter one days worth of data, like:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T1
>   ([val] int, [createDate] datetime)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO T1
>   ([val], [createDate])
> VALUES
>   (1, '2019-11-03 00:00:00'),
>   (2, '2019-11-03 00:00:00'),
>   (3, '2019-11-02 00:00:00'),
>   (4, '2019-11-02 00:00:00'),
>   (5, '2019-11-01 00:00:00')
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T2
>   ([val] int, [createDate] datetime)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select Convert(date, dateadd(day,-1,getdate()))  
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)    |
> | :------------------ |
> | 02/11/2019 00:00:00 |
> ```

> ```
> insert into T2
> select * from T1
> where createDate = Convert(date, dateadd(day,-1,getdate()))  
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from T2
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> val | createDate         
> --: | :------------------
>   3 | 02/11/2019 00:00:00
>   4 | 02/11/2019 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ad4c7b266d07d04c977968193046d04)*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @IT WeiHan, you do not have to make a linked server, the data transfer can be done by the import data wizard:

[image]